Stationary phase formula for a complex valued phase
I'd be interested in computing an asymptotic expansion when $h \rightarrow 0$, of an integral of the form
$$
I_h = \int_{\mathbb{R}}{e^{\frac{i}{h}\varphi(x)}dx}
$$
where $\varphi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ extends to a holomorphic function on a neighbourhood of $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ (I'm happy to assume that it extends to the whole of $\mathbb{C}$ if it simplifies matters).
I've heard of the existence of a "complex" stationary phase formula allowing to compute this expansion in terms of the critical points of $\varphi : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ but couldn't find a satisfactory reference for that. Any idea where I could find such a result?

A standard reference is F. W. J. Olver, Asymptotics and special functions (1974).

See Asymptotic expansions of oscillatory integrals with complex phase (2010). The usual formulas carry through even if $\phi(x)$ is complex, provided that it has a non-negative imaginary part.
